# RegEx for rejecting all strings containing a period except a combination?

Tags: regex

How would I make a RegEx that rejects all strings containing a period between quotes unless that period was preceded by a number sign?

```
[^.]*
```

Will reject anything with a period but how do I do the exception to this?

Comment: What language are you in? Because it's usually easier to match - then negate, than negative match.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
^(?!.*?"[^"]*(?<!\d)\.[^"]*").+
```

[**Here's a demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jF6wH9/1); note the unit tests (link on lower left).

The idea is to match any string (the `^` and final `.+`), but reject it if it matches `.*?"[^"]*(?<!\d)\.[^"]*"`: any characters, a `"`, any non-`"` characters, a `.` not preceded by a digit, any non-`"` characters, and another `"`.

Examples:

```
Foo               matches
foo "bar"         matches
"foo" bar         matches
Foo "bar."        does not match
Foo "Bar. Baz"    does not match
"Foo" bar "Baz."  does not match
Foo "bar 3."      matches
Foo "3."          matches
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
".*#\..*"|"[^.]*?"
```

It captures both `"abc"` and `"a#.bc"` but rejects `"a.bc"`

First it will try to match a string between quotes that contains a number sign followed by a period. Then if it does not match it will match the shortest string beteween quotes that does not contain a period

Cheers